# What tool will help me reduce the bandwidth usage of a website?

Tags: html, optimization, web

I was thinking to start optimizing a website that I own by decreasing code and images sent to the client hoping to improve download speed rates. Is there any tool around that could help me optimize my website by telling me each time the total bandwidth used by the page that I am optimizing? and then giving me a total report based on the sitemap of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

One way that really helps is to localize any Javascript that you have and pack it.

Comment: Nice one. But to use this tool I must test the page after I upload it. What about testing it before uploading ?

Comment: You could host it locally...however, take note that everyone's connection is different. You don't want to look at bandwidth, you want to look at overall page size.

Comment: ye page size is the key point here. Anyway I think this tools helps allot. The only problem is that when I have php files or asp files that generate html content. Those needed to be measured. But I have my ip public now and I can use the tool you gave me directly on my localhost by my public up. Thank you again